# XP pen 15.6 artist display whitening in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: display-resolution, tablet, graphics-tablet, pentesting

I have installed ubuntu 22.10 and installed drivers of XP pen 15.6.
I am facing display whitening issues at the bottom of the tabletas shown below:

[image]

So if you can see in the image, half of the pen tab screen is white. Also the screen flickers a lot. I adjusted resolution of the screen too, but no use. What is the issue please please help

Comment: Try reinstalling the display driver.

Comment: No use i already did it

Comment: Try going to a XORG session.If you don't know how to do that, follow this [link](https://beebom.com/how-switch-between-wayland-xorg-ubuntu/).

Comment: ok i will try tq very much. After trying i will reply here

Comment: Rishon JR, i have moved to xorg.....happy to inform that display is fine now. But i am unable to mirror my laptop activity on tablet. I can see only the desktop view of ubuntu. I cannot see any mouse movements on tablet

Comment: Rishon Tq very much, I finally fixed it in xorg mode. U really helpmed a lot, Tq

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Hi rishon, one more help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445882/displays-option-not-showing-for-mirroring-pen-tablet

Comment: @Rishon_JR can you help here.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1502327/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-freezing-with-mouse-active

Comment: I have lost touch with linux and i'm really sorry. I can't help you.