# Displays option not showing for Mirroring Pen tablet

Tags: display, settings, graphics-tablet, mirrors

I am using ubuntu 22.04, After restart, i could not see displays in settings option. I am getting no signal error on my pen tablet, but pen is detected. Here is the image where only Built In display is shown but not Pen tab:

[image]

Comment: How are you connected through?

Comment: HDMI+USB rishon, could you eloborate more?

Comment: As you suggested, i am using xorg

Comment: Both USB and HDMI? I don't get it. or your connected through HDMI and using a convertor on one end?

Comment: Rishon, HDMI cable for display and USB for pen...both cables joined for my pen tab

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions rishon, i badly need help :)

Comment: To be honest, i'm not an expert in these things.Try reconnecting the HDMI. If it doesn't work, Does your tablet have an OS installed? If so try using remote desktop software.

Comment: No OS rishon, just a graphics tablet. But its working fine in Windows

Comment: The only possible solution that i can think of is to get an updated kernel(updated drivers, of course) by doing `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @ Rishon please help here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450748/time-sync-problem-after-entering-to-windows-from-ubuntu

Comment: Look, I get that you are facing many inconveniences using ubuntu. But please do not just ask me alone. I have expertise in package management and software development. For others, I could make guesses.

Comment: @Rishon sorry....its just a trust on u :)