# Time sync problem after running Windows after exiting from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, sync, time

After using Ubuntu 22.10 and I restart the PC I run windows 10. The time shown is different from the current time. Hence every time I come to Windows from Ubuntu I have to manually change the time. Please help with this issue.

Comment: If you have more than one OS on your system, you want to ensure they both use the same timezone data.   Ubuntu like all GNU/Linux, BSD or internet aware OSes uses UTC or universal/internet time by default; windows default time depends on install but can use Redmond/Washington time (if online for some versions), Local time (if offline during install for most versions), or UTC time - ie. how windows was installed will dictate the time.  Make the two systems use the same default & you won't have issues; you can alter your Ubuntu, or alter your Windows system to use the other's default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot) This is an old question but the explanation and solutions are the same today. I suggest that you change Windows to derive local time from UTC, instead of setting the system clock to local time.

Comment: You''ll have to enable an option in BIOS settings to sync OS time and System time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default Ubuntu user interface, then you just go into time settings and force the automatic sync. Once you pick the time zone it should boot up and set it right when the ntp loads up in the system servces.

Ubuntu looks at time very differently... As a UTC+offset, where Windows expects the system clock to be your local time, Ubuntu will set the system clock to UTC. But, if the sync and timezone is on then you shouldn't have a problem but for a moment. Windows syncs as well, because if the clock is off by even a full second it breaks all sorts of things to do with encryption and networking.