# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS freezing with mouse active

Tags: 22.04, intel-graphics, freeze

I am facing annoying issue of freezing of Ubuntu with mouse active.

But when I turn off my XP-Pen pen tablet, its normal. But again after 10-15 min it freezes.

Here is my "about" details

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Please [edit] with the relevant log entries from `journalctl -r`